# Is there a word to describe "see wrongly"?

Tags: word-request

**e.g.** ***mis**understood, **mis**read*

It does not sound formal to say *"understood wrongly"* or *"read wrongly"*. The only way to make it sounds formal is to use a single word to describe that act.

However, I cannot think of a word to describe *"see wrongly"* although it is commonly spoken (in Singapore).

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate, but I want to emphasize that this was not a punitive action. This is a good question, and you did a great job writing it!